# FB ID's when registering with multiple apps to a third party SSO (Gigya) migrated after adding to a Business Identity with in FB

Tags: facebook

We've created multiple Facebook apps for different Apps. The first app was released before the app was added to the business identity. The second app showed us that we needed to add both Facebook apps associated to the APP's to our business identity. My question is:
Will the identifiers that Facebook sends when registering to the third party sso for users who have registered before the app was part of the BI cause any problems? I.o.w. When I have registered before the integration of the FB app into our business identity will the id that was send to our SSO (Gigya) will get that same id when registering with the second app when both apps are now part of the same business identity or will the id's be different? (Does Facebook do some sort of merge of id's?)

Answer (score 1):

Gigya's integration not only knows about Facebook's Business Manager but utilizes its API to allow us a single view of the user on our side.

Facebook does not migrate IDs, using their Business Manager to simplify integration across multiple external Facebook apps.  So long as an app uses the [Business Mapping API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business#api), it can associate a user ID on one app with any other that the user is logged into.  This is regardless of the actual IDs that are used in the app itself.

Gigya SSO will work across your apps now that both apps are in your Business manager.